# Mysqli Query results returns empty but shouldn't

Tags: php, mysqli

I run the query directly through PHP MyAdmin and it returns 1 result.  Am I missing something? Well clearly I must be and I can't wrap my head round it!?!

I think I'm just tired or something!
Any help would be much appreciated:-

```
$query_road_tax = mysqli_query($conn011, "SELECT * FROM road_tax_pricing WHERE (tax_from_co2 <='$vehicle_co2' AND tax_upto_co2 >='$vehicle_co2'");
$row_road_tax = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_road_tax);
$Six_Month=$row_road_tax['tax_6month'];
$Twelve_Month=$row_road_tax['tax_12month'];
```

Comment: check whether the connection string that you have given is exactly same as that which is written in your conection page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Closing `) and "` issue it would be

```
$query_road_tax = mysqli_query($conn011, "SELECT * FROM 
road_tax_pricing WHERE (tax_from_co2 <='$vehicle_co2' AND tax_upto_co2 >='$vehicle_co2')");
```

Comment: Thank you soooo much!!!  I just couldn't see it through the red strain of my eyes!!!

Answer (score 1):

Try that - you might have to print the results in loop.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM road_tax_pricing WHERE (tax_from_co2 <='$vehicle_co2' AND tax_upto_co2 >='$vehicle_co2')";

if($query_road_tax = mysqli_query($conn011, $query)) {
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_road_tax)) {

      /* print_r($row); */

      printf($row["tax_6month"]);
      printf($row["tax_12month"]);
  }
}
```